# Module import failing in Next.js: <module name>__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...).<function name> is not a function

Tags: typescript, next.js, jimp

I've got a barebones Next.js project (w/ TypeScript) to which I've added Jimp. I'm using the experimental `app` dir in my config.

My `next.config.js` looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

In my `page.tsx`, whenever I'm attempting to add Jimp by `import Jimp from 'jimp';` and invoke its `read` function

```
useEffect(() => {

  // ...

  (async () => {
    const img = await Jimp.read(file);
  })();

  // ...

}, []);
```

I've got the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: jimp__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...).read is not a function`, also `console.log(Jimp.read)` gives me `undefined`.

What I am missing here?

Comment: try using `use client` to do client-side rendering. or `import Jimp from "jimp/es";`

Comment: Neither worked. I've been using `'use client'` all along, and `import Jimp from "jimp/es"` just gave me the error message `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`.
I suspect Next.js doesn't appreciate the fact that Jimp makes use of Node.js's core lib `fs`.

Comment: try manually   installing fs once

Comment: Adding 'fs' manually did it, thanks a bunch.
I also needed to add the following to my `module.exports` in `next.config.js`:

```javascript
const nextConfig = {

// ...

  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };
    return config;
  }

// ...

}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: Okay great. Yes few config needs to be update for webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try manually installing fs once. `npm install fs --save`. You might need to change some configuration for webpack

Comment: Can you please clarify why it should be installed from npm when the module is a security holding package?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs